# Freeze an Integer

Tags: java, if-statement, integer

I'm working on an app that uses lot's of ImageButtons and on every onTouch event on those ImageButtons a value is added to an Integer variable. Here comes the problem, let's say I have this statement that returns true  at a certain point:

```
if (x == y)
```

How can I make the integerVariable to stay the same even if the user touches again those images?
For example something like this:

```
if (x == y){ integerVariable will not change};
```

Comment: Do not assign anything to it anymore?

Comment: post the code where you add the integer variabe

Comment: I was thinking about doing that... but that will require to rewrite a good part of the code. I assumed that I was missing something here from the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could control this via a custom boolean. It's for reasons like this (custom, non standard field access) that getters and setters are suggested.

Only ever use the setter `setMyInt(int value)` in your code and never access the field directly and you will be ok. If you need to know whether the value was updated, look at the returned boolean.

```
private int myInt;
private boolean isMyIntLocked = false;

public boolean setMyInt(int value) {
    if (isMyIntLocked) {
        Log.i(TAG, "cannot set myInt, it's been locked");
        return false;
    } else {
        this.myInt = value;
        return true;
    }
}

public void lockMyInt(boolean doLock) {
    this.isMyIntLocked = doLock;
}
```

Comment: With some changes to my code but using your logic it worked! Thank's a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `boolean` to check if the integer should be incremented or not.

Your variables:

```
boolean increment = true;
int x = 0, y = 1;
```

When a user clicks the X button:

```
if(increment)
    x++;

if(x == y)
    increment = false;
```